# PHP mail form won't send with spaces in email field

Tags: php, forms, email

**My Problem:**
I have a Contact Form that gets sent to an email address. It normally works fine, but the form will not send if spaces are included in the 'Email' Text Field (where the person sending the mail would enter their email). If any other form has spaces the form will still send.

I know spaces aren't allowed in email addresses, but if the message is sent with spaces in the email field, users are still taken to a different page stating the message has been sent, when it actually hasn't. So if someone accidentally puts a space while entering the email, the website will not send the form but it will say it did.

**Here's how I have it set up:**
On the form the email field is automatically populated by what the user has stored as their User Account email. This variable is then passed using `POST` to a different page 'wl_process.php' where the fields are sent to an email address. However, even though it automatically fills the email field in for The User, they may want to have their response sent back to a different email.

**What I'm trying to do, and not to do:**
I'm not sure why including spaces would stop the mail from being sent. I want it to send the form even if spaces are included. I'm looking for a PHP tag or method where all spaces are stripped from the text field. I'm not sure if that exists. I think another solution may be to check for spaces in the email, and if spaces are there have something pop-up and say "Invalid Email Entered, please try again." But ideally, I just want it to send the email. And also, if anyone knows why it's doing this, that would be very beneficial for future use.

**Additional Info**

Keep in mind that the form works perfectly until spaces are entered into the Email field. If spaces are entered in any of the other fields, the form will still send!

Also: $var_email is pulled from a `<? include?>` that is located at the top of the page. The include has some `$_SESSION` information, and also the `MYSQLI` call that grabs the email out of the databse and turns into a PHP variable. I doubt this has anything to do with the problem though. My problem is *the spaces will stop the mail from being sent*.

**What Doesn't Matter**

My naming conventions. Don't get thrown off and think my variable named `$email` is ever treated like an Email Address in any manner. It could be renamed anything. It is only a variable and text-field here, being posted then Emailed.

**My Code**

*Page 1* (Where the form is)

```
<div class="form_box">
...
    <div class="field clearfix">
      <label>Email <span>&#42;</span></label>
      <input id="element_1_email" name="element_1_email" value="<? echo $var_email;?>" size="30" class="validate[optional]" type="text" onClick="(this).value=''"/>
    </div>
```

*Page 2* (Where the data is sent and mailed out)

```
    <?
 $name = $_POST['element_0_name'];
 $email = $_POST['element_1_email'];
 $company = $_POST['element_2_company'];
 $date = $_POST['element_3_date'];
 $comment = $_POST['element_4_comment'];
 $list = $_POST['element_5_list'];
 $email_to = "contact@website.com";
 $email_subject = "Online Form";
 $email_message = "\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array ("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
        return str_replace($bad, "",$string);
    }
    $email_message .= '<div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding-left: 90px;font-weight: 100;font-size: 14px;color: #2a2a2a;"><table width="1070px" height="685px;"border="0" cellspacing="0" background="http://www.website/image.jpg">
                    <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align:top;padding-left:88px;">
                    <h2 style="padding-top:150px;padding-left:90px;">Form Information:</h2>';   
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."<br>";
    $email_message .= "Email: " .clean_string($email). "<br>";
    $email_message .= "Company: " .clean_string($company). "<br>";
    $email_message .= "Date Required: " .clean_string($date). "<br>";
    $email_message .= "Comment: " .clean_string($comment). "<br>";
    $email_message .= '<u>List Of Things:<style> tr:nth-child(2n) {background-color:#d6d6d6;}</style> </u><br><table cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:10px;min-width:390px;border:1px solid #cccccc;">' .clean_string($list). '</table>';
    $email_message .= "</div>";

    $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '. $email."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' .phpversion();
    $headers .= "MIME-Version:1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
 //
 ?>
```

Comment: I don't think spaces are allowed in email addresses, so the attempt to "send the email anyway" won't work.  The real problem here is that you're telling the user that the email was successfully sent without actually *checking* if it was successfully sent.  If the call to `@mail()` results in an error then the user should be told that there was an error.

Comment: You're not checking the return value of `mail()`, so you're assuming the email is sent. In fact, with the @, you're suppressing any error messages that you might be getting.

Comment: Yes, but the 'Email Field' is just a text-field like any other field. It has nothing to do with where the form is sent. It simply tells the receiver what the senders' email address is. It could be called 'Address' or 'City'.

Comment: Somehow you are not getting that your wish to send the email even if the emailaddress is invalid will never lead to a message really being sent. With the '@' you are surpressing errormessages. Messages you could use to tell the user something went wrong. Even if you filtered out the spaces from the emailaddress entered, there is still no guarantee it results in a valid/existing emailaddress.

Comment: @user2118228 - not really. Some mail servers check the validity of the From headers in emails they receive, and if it's not a valid address, it won't send the email.

Comment: @andrewsi - In my form the text-field named 'Email' has nothing to do with that. It's just a text-field like the rest. It should be able to have spaces. The only reason it's associated with anything 'Email' is because I named it that way.

Comment: But, Error messages aside, does anyone know why my form isn't being mailed if a 'Certain' text field has spaces in it? What would cause the mailer to break?

Comment: I can't see a text field called `email`. Do you mean `element_1_email`, or is there a field I've missed?

Comment: Yep, that's the one. I think it's still being treated as php along the way somewhere so it would need to be concatinated when a 'space' is added. That's the only thing I can think of why the 'php is breaking'...

Comment: @user2118228 - right. You're setting $email to be the value of that form input. And then you're passing $email into mail via `$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n"`

Comment: @user2118228 - so if $email is badly formed, the From line of your email will also be badly formed. You're passing the value entered by the user into the mail header (aside from the issue you're having, you're also open to mail header injections, too)

Comment: Isn't `$email` turned into HTML at that point though? Even if it wasn't - why would that stop it from being sent?

Comment: @user2118228 - it's never turned into HTML. You're using its value as part of $email_message, but you're not changing the original value anywhere. I assume that your mail server is set up to parse email addresses, and to reject emails with invalid ones.

Comment: I was referring to $var_email being echoed in the HTML form being turned from databse --> PHP ---> HTML. But I think I might just be mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just strip out the spaces from the `$_POST` variable on Page 2?

Change this

```
$email = $_POST['element_1_email'];
```

to this

```
$email = str_replace(' ','',$_POST['element_1_email']);
```

----------- **UPDATE** -----------

Your message is failing because of this code in your `$headers` variable:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".'Reply-To: '. $email."\r\n" .
```

You are using `$email` here which did not go through your `clean_string` function (where you could also remove the spaces by adding   a `space` to the `$bad` array), so essentially you are trying to send the email to whatever was received in `$_POST['element_1_email']` without any sort of clean up or email validation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Bonus kudos if you can tell my why spaces are messing my script up...

Comment: You could also bounce it back by doing a [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) on the string, searching for the space, if true, don't submit and prompt the user to correct it.